# Javascript concatenating string and variable to create url - but doesn't output "/" slashes

Tags: javascript

I am building HTML in JavaScript which is working fine however I have encountered something haven't seen before and am not finding obvious solution to get past this.

I am trying to create url by concatenating string and variable but it isn't outputting `"/"` slashes.

I am building on the `html` variable which starts off creating a table:

```
var html = '<table class="table table-bordered">';
html += '<td><a href="https://twitter.com/' + columns[1] +'">' + columns[1] + '</a></td>';
```

However this outputs everything except the `"/"` slashes and adds `</href="https:>` in place of `</a>`:

```
<a href="https: twitter.com="" toptechstaffing"="">TopTechStaffing</href="https:>
```

Is this not possible in JavaScript? In other languages I have seen use of backslashes to escape foreslashes so they can be presented eg  `"\/"`

What is the "common" way of doing this in JavaScript?

---

Edited to add:

The `columns[1]` variable was a string.

Comment: That's not valid HTML, there are no `<href>` elements that look like that. Do `<a href="..` instead. That's a typo !

Comment: Oops yes typo thx

Comment: @curtisp var twitterURL = "https://twitter.com/"     <a href="+ twitterURL  + columns[1] +">   put your url in a variable and assign that variable

Comment: Please post your `columns` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var html = "";

html += "<td><a href=\"https://twitter.com/" + columns[1] + "\">" + columns[1] + "</a></td>";
```

Comment: Ah ok the backslash goes up front! That worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works well, assuming there is no slashes contained in column[1]

```
var html='<table class="table table-bordered">';

    html+="<td><a href='https:\//twitter.com\/" + columns[1] + "'>"+ columns[1] + "</a></td>";
```